# Kotlin: Returning random elements from a list

Tags: kotlin, random

I'm having some trouble getting and returning random elements from a couple of lists (String and int).
The problem is that every time I run the code, the values are indeed random. But for consecutive calls of the same method(s), the values are similar.

I've reduced my code down to the important parts, so there are no class definitions, imports etc. included in the sample here.

```
lonnsinntekter2 += TestsakDataBuilder.createInntekt(
    fnr = fnr, arbeid = TestsakDataBuilder.createArbeid()

fun createArbeid(arbeidsgiver: String = randomArbeidsgiver, stillingsprosent: Int = 
                               randomStillingsprosent,
                               erStillingFast: Boolean = HelperUtils.getRandomBoolean()): Arbeid {
    return Arbeid.builder()
        .arbeidsgiver(arbeidsgiver)
        .stillingsprosent(stillingsprosent)
        .erStillingFast(erStillingFast)
        .build()
    }   
}
```

The **randomArbeidsgiver** and **randomStillingsprosent** methods called from the above code:

```
val randomArbeidsgiver = listOf("Snusk & Fransen AS", "Humbug Elektro AS", "Hummer & Kanari ANS",
        "REMA1000", "Meny", "Gaukern på hjørnet", "Equinor", "Ad Libris").random()

val randomStillingsprosent = listOf(50, 60, 70, 80, 90).random()
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it that the .random() function of the list selects the value at compile time, and not for each call?

Comment: `randomArbeidsgiver` and `randomStillingsprosent` isn't methods or functions, it's [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

Comment: you can either switch `randomArbeidsgiver` and `randomStillingsprosent` to a function or just insert `get()` before the `=` which basically always reevaluates the given code when the value is requested...

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon or global variables :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, **randomArbeidsgiver** and **randomStillingsprosent** are *NOT* methods.
If you wish to make them methods, simply add curly braces around them.

However, this will initialize the list every time the method is called.

Example:

```
val randomArbeidsgiver = {
    listOf("Snusk & Fransen AS", "Humbug Elektro AS", "Hummer & Kanari ANS",
            "REMA1000", "Meny", "Gaukern på hjørnet", "Equinor", "Ad Libris").random() 
}

val randomStillingsprosent = { listOf(50, 60, 70, 80, 90).random() }

fun test(item1: String = randomArbeidsgiver(), item2: Int = randomStillingsprosent()) {
    println("Item 1: $item1")
    println("Item 2: $item2")
}
```

Try the example: https://pl.kotl.in/N-7Lkw-ng

Answer (score 5):

`random()` is only invoked **once** for each of your variables `randomArbeidsgiver` and `randomStillingsprosent` when the programm starts. After that you work with the value that has been assigned.

If you want to retrieve new random elements each time `createArbeid` is called, you could decouple the list creation from the random element retrieval like that:

```
val arbeidsgiverList = listOf("Snusk & Fransen AS", "Humbug Elektro AS", "Hummer & Kanari ANS", "REMA1000", "Meny", "Gaukern på hjørnet", "Equinor", "Ad Libris")
val stillingsprosentList = listOf(50, 60, 70, 80, 90)

fun createArbeid(
    arbeidsgiver: String = arbeidsgiverList.random(), 
    stillingsprosent: Int = stillingsprosentList.random(), 
    ...
): Arbeid { /* ... */}
```